# capture using v4l2 and display preview using gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer, v4l2

How to pass the buffer/userpointer to gstreamer after Q_BUF, STREAM_ON, DQ_BUF.

I tried using PIL's method frombuffer, but with no success. so I want to use gst sink now.

Should I use gst.parse_launch() and how?

Have anybody done it?

Comment: Maybe this can help?

https://launchpad.net/elisa-plugin-v4l2

Specifically:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rui.castro/elisa-plugin-v4l2/devel/annotate/head%3A/models.py

Comment: I am not that in to gstreamer. I'd like a simpler example :)

Answer (score 0):

The source code to Cheese tells all. http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/